# Свой формат поля и автозамена MS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Нужно создать текстовое поле в таблице формата "аа-0000аааа"
(не обязательны буквы, но обязательны 4 цифры)

Кто нибудь решал подобные задачи? Не могу в работу с проверкой введенных данных и автозаменой аля (8 -> 0008, 20абв->0020абв, с-10 -> С-0010 и т.п.)

Есть набросок триггера на замену и вот думаю, как его можно модифицировать под решение конкретно этой задачи.

```
CREATE TRIGGER testTrigger ON dbo.test
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE AS
DECLARE @new_str nvarchar(32);
SET @new_str = SELECT test FROM dbo.test
    UPDATE dbo.test
    SET test = @new_str
    FROM dbo.test
```

Очень надеюсь на вашу помощь!

Вроде потихоньку начинаю разбираться.

Ввел ограничение к полю:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.test
    ADD CONSTRAINT testt CHECK(LEN(testt)=11 AND testt LIKE '[А-Я][А-Я]-[0000-9999][А-Я][А-Я][А-Я][А-Я]')
```

Возникли еще несколько вопросов:
1. Как сделать заглавными только 2 первые буквы? оператор UPPER() делает заглавными ВСЕ буквы в поле.
2. Как из 1-3х значного числа сделать 4х значное?

Comment: вы сначала саму функцию напишите, потом уже про триггер подумаете.

Comment: @teran задание реализовать это в триггере, да и не совсем понимаю как это реализовать даже в функции...

Comment: Вопрос нужно срочно решить(